# OnPreferenceChangeListener fires before change is made

Tags: android

For the following code:

```
final SwitchPreference sp = (SwitchPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_key_reminder));
        sp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
                AlarmReceiver.scheduleAlarm(getActivity());
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I need the changed value of switch preferance, but the value in `preferance` is the value before change is made. Object `o` has the new value, but how do I set that in the preference before `AlarmReceiver.scheduleAlarm` is called. That method uses the value of the preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the `SwitchPreference` changes the underlying `SharedPreferences` value **after** the `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.onPreferenceChange` is called, see the code from `SwitchPreference`:

```
private class Listener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (!callChangeListener(isChecked)) { // callback here
            // Listener didn't like it, change it back.
            // CompoundButton will make sure we don't recurse.
            buttonView.setChecked(!isChecked);
            return;
        }

        SwitchPreference.this.setChecked(isChecked); // save value here
    }
}

/**
 * Sets the checked state and saves it to the {@link SharedPreferences}.
 *
 * @param checked The checked state.
 */
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    // Always persist/notify the first time; don't assume the field's default of false.
    final boolean changed = mChecked != checked;
    if (changed || !mCheckedSet) {
        mChecked = checked;
        mCheckedSet = true;
        persistBoolean(checked);
        if (changed) {
            notifyDependencyChange(shouldDisableDependents());
            notifyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you call:

```
AlarmReceiver.scheduleAlarm(getActivity());
```

and retrieve the value from `SharedPreferences`, you will get the old value. So, you may defer your calling to `AlarmReceiver.scheduleAlarm`, for example, using a `Handler`:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    AlarmReceiver.scheduleAlarm(getActivity());
});
```